# Problem with copying a single item of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new at Java and I came across a problem I couldn't find a solution to, so maybe somebody can help me out. When I write this code:

```java
ArrayList<String> Liste = new ArrayList<>();
String Name;

Liste.add("Harry");
Name = Liste.get(0);
Name = "Dieter";

System.out.print(Liste.get(0));
System.out.print(Name);
```

The output is, as expected:

```
Harry
Dieter
```

However, if I change the type to a custom object:

```java
ArrayList<Names_Class> Liste = new ArrayList<>();
Names_Class Name;

Liste.add(new Names_Class());
Liste.get(0).First_Name = "Harry";
Name = Liste.get(0);
Name.First_Name = "Dieter";

System.out.print(Liste.get(0));
System.out.print(Name);
```

The output becomes:

```
Dieter
Dieter
```

So it seems Java only copies a references or something. Could somebody explain what happens here, and how I can get a complete copy of a single item out of an ArrayList?

Comment: See also: [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869033/5923139)

Comment: *"seems java only copies a reference"* That is correct. It's why they (`Liste` and `Name`) are known as *reference variables*.

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for *variable* names to start with lowercase letter, so they should be `liste` and `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

String type is stored in Stack.
Object type is stored in Heap.

```
Liste.add("Harry");
```

You added a string value "Harry" somewhere in stack.

```
Name = Liste.get(0);
```

Then you gave it a reference name "Name"

```
"Dieter";
```

You created a new value 'Dieter' somewhere in stack.

```
Name = "Dieter";
```

'Name' now references the location of stack where 'Dieter' is stored.

```
System.out.print(Liste.get(0));
```

Liste.get(0) references 'Harry'.

```
System.out.print(Name);
```

'Name' references 'Dieter'

Meanwhile,

```
Liste.add(new Names_Class());
```

new Names_Class() appoints some memery space in heap for Names_Class()

```
Liste.get(0).First_Name = "Harry";
```

First object of Liste - First_Name references 'Harry'

```
Name = Liste.get(0);
```

'Name' references what Liste.get(0) is referencing.

```
Name.First_Name = "Dieter";
```

'Name' - First_Name references 'Dieter'
This is identical as Liste.get(0).First_Name = "Dieter".

```
System.out.print(Liste.get(0));
System.out.print(Name);
```

They both prints same value since Name references same location as Liste.get(0)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This together with the Link from Aplet123 helped me solve my problem :)